# How to add an embedded source file editor(or text area) for an IDEA plugin?

Tags: groovy, intellij-plugin

i am making an IDEA plugin with a text area for groovy script.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvHWn.png)

how to make this area with grammer checking and auto-completion like IDE source file editor like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHk6c.png)